# How can I reset a preventDefault in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my Drupal 7 site I have some checkout pages where I need to check if a field value is changed or not after a form is submitted. If it is not changed I want to show a message to remind the customer to fill in the field. In some few cases it might happen that the field should remain empty or unchanged, so I need to take that into account too.

This is what I got so far:

```
  function extracheck(){
    var checkfield = document.querySelector("#edit-continue") !== null;
      if (checkfield){
      document.getElementById("edit-continue").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        var alertfield = document.getElementById('edit-customer-profile-kompl-info-field-ert-ordernummer-und-0-value');
        if (alertfield.value == alertfield.defaultValue) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('#edit-customer-profile-kompl-info-field-ert-ordernummer-und-0-value').css("background-color", "#FFFF33");
            $('#output-box').addClass('output-box-style');
             document.getElementById("output-box").innerHTML = "The highlighted field is empty. Do you really want to continue?<br><br><div class='button tiny' id='btn1'>YES, continue</div><div class='button tiny' id='btn2'>NO, I want to edit the field</div>";
             btn1.addEventListener("click", yesfunction, false);
             btn2.addEventListener("click", nofunction, false);
             return false;
        }
      }, false);
    }
  }

  extracheck();

  function yesfunction(){
    document.getElementById('commerce-checkout-form-checkout').submit();
  }
  function nofunction(){
      $('#output-box').css("display","none");
      // here I need to "undo" the preventDefault set above
  }
```

First I need to check if this specific submit button exists on the page (with the id `#edit-continue`).
Then by using `value` and `defaultValue` I compare the initial state of the field's value with the current state. If the field is unchanged i bind a `preventDefault` action to the submit button, so the form isn't submitted. I then highlight the field and show a DIV box with the question "The highlighted field is empty. Do you really want to continue?" and 2 buttons: "Yes, I want to continue" and "No, I want to edit the field".

I then bind 2 eventlisteners to the buttons and assign them to the external functions `nofunction()` and `yesfunction()`. If the customer clicks yes, the form is submitted. If he clicks no, I hide the message box. I could have just reloaded the page, but then all values filled in in all other fields would be cleared.

So I need to just hide the box and then undo or reset the preventDefault action on the submit button, so the form can be submitted the normal way.

I am banging my head and have tried all I can think of. Does anyone have an idea on how I can let the form be submitted normallly after hiding the message box? I have tried to use removeEventListener and to use a function that returns true on the submit button element.

Everything works fine otherwise, if the field is unchanged the box opens, if the field is changed the form is submitted normally. If the field is unchanged and the user decides to continue all the same and clicks Yes, the form is also submitted.

Comment: you can't "undo or reset the preventDefault action", but you can just [tell the form to submit itself](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit).

Comment: Okay, I suspected as much in the end... I ended up adding $('#output-box').css("display","inline-block"); to show the message again if the submit button was clicked without changing tie field's value. forcing the user to use the YES button instead (to submit the form). Thanks for the info.